# Open Sourcing Commissioned Art

Tags: copyright, commercial, art

Some friends and I started up a very small business venue a while back, to make a card game. Properly registered as a partnership and all that. It was nothing serious though, just something we worked on in our spare time.

We've all gotten busy, and so are likely to drop it (technically I exitted 3 months ago). No one is unhappy about this, we had fun.

During the project we spend a few hundred dollars commissioning art.
I think we ended about with 10 or so images.
Which we bought outright (not licensed, but fully purchased the copyright).
It is generally really good, we got great deals from our artists.

If we wanted to open source it are there any particular concerns given that we were not the original creators?

Answer (score 5):

If you are the legal owners of the copyright, you are certainly entitled to license it as you want, including making it open. But as images, you should probably look for the Creative Commons licenses.

Comment: As a note: many open-source licenses or open-content licenses demand that the author is credited. In most european countries this is always a demand as these rights cannot be sold. So you might set the license as you like, but still have to credit the original artist.

Comment: @Mnementh, you are certainly right. I was thinking of adding that (even if just out of courtesy) it would be nice to credit the original author (i.e., use CC-BY), but didn't in the end. Thanks!

Comment: I'd like to add that while, legally speaking, you are likely fine, it would be nice to ask the artist first, and abide by their wishes.

Comment: I was thinking CC0